# How to add a "rel" attribute to images from a div container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want javascript to add this rel attribute **rel="lightbox[1]"** to all images from a given container when the page loads...

Is that possible?

```
<div id="otherimg">
   <p><img src="" alt="" /></p>
   <p><img src="" alt="" /></p>
   <p><img src="" alt="" /></p>
   <p><img src="" alt="" /></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#otherimg img').attr('rel', 'lightbox[1]')
})
```

Comment: `$(function() { ... })` is shorthand for `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 1):

this will add to only the `img` tags inside `div` with id `otherimg`

```
$(function() {

$('div#otherimg img').attr("rel", "lightbox[1]")

})
```